# LD iisadmpwd - change expired password

Tags: active-directory, passwords

I need to be able to allow users to change their expired password using \iisadmpwd utility inside IIS

It looks as though if your password is expired, you can't authenticate into AD and therefore can not change your password.

What are my options?

Answer (score 1):

There is a hotfix that appears to address this problem.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/833734